# Python3 Switch not working, return all case

Tags: python, switch-statement

i'm new with python, i try to make a switch-case implementation in python, I already found out about this but its not working. it return all of this case

```
if not (data.message is None):
    if data.message[0] == "/":
        command = data.message.split("/")
        if not (command[1] is None):
            switcher = {
                "location" : funcA(data.id),
                "carousel" : funcB(data.id, data.name),
                "button" : funcC(data.id),
                "card" : funcD(data.id, data.name)
            }
            return switcher.get(command[1], funcE())
        else:
            return funcE()
    else:
        return funcE()
```

then, i test input command[1] with '/asd' , it will return all of function.

Comment: Why do you have two identical `else` clauses? Specificaly, what's happening here that you don't expect? Instead of `if not (foo is None)`, try `if foo is not None`.

Comment: `funcA(data.id)` will execute the function immediately.  You want just `funcA` as a dict value and `return switcher.get(command[1], funcE)(data.id)`

Comment: `split` won't return a list containing `None`, only a non-empty list of `str` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @snakecharmerb mentioned, in your dictionary values, you should be *naming* the functions not calling them:

```
switcher = {
    "location" : funcA,
    "carousel" : funcB,
    "button" : funcC,
    "card" : funcD
}
```

And specify the argument `data.id` in the `return` statement, if the key exists in the dictionary:

```
return switcher[command[1]](data.id) if command[1] in switcher else funcE()
```

Also, you can replace `if not (data.message is None)` with `if message` and combine it with `data.message[0] == "/"`.

As pointed out by @Mark Bailey, since you're already checking if `command[1]` is in `switcher`, you can remove the second `if` statement altogether.

All in all:

```
if data.message and data.message[0] == "/":
    command = data.message.split("/")
    switcher = {
        "location" : funcA,
        "carousel" : funcB,
        "button" : funcC,
        "card" : funcD
    }
    return switcher[command[1]](data.id) if command[1] in switcher else funcE()
else:
    return funcE()
```

Edit: To support passing a variable number of arguments to the functions, you can specify an argument list in the dictionary, and pass it to the function with unpacking:

```
if data.message and data.message[0] == "/":
    command = data.message.split("/")
    switcher = {
        "location" : [funcA,[data.id,data.name]],
        "carousel" : [funcB,[data.id]],
        "button" : [funcC,[data.id,data.name]],
        "card" : [funcD,[data.id,data.name, data.time]]
    }
    return switcher[command[1]][0](*switcher[command[1]][1]) if command[1] in switcher else funcE()
else:
    return funcE()
```

Comment: I'd also suggest moving the switcher definition up, out of the if, so then you can do a simple `if command[1] in switcher:` with a single `else` catchall.

Comment: how if each function has different parameters, e.g. funcA(data.id) then funcB(data.id,data.name)?

Comment: @MarkBailey thank you, for your suggestion i'll try it

Comment: @iskandarsuhaimi updated my answer to support a variable number of arguments